# Clear a specific place on the screen

Tags: c++

clear a specific place on the Console by C++ 17 in vs2017, like this:

```
hello guys, I want to clear something, pls help me.
```

**clear → want**  or  **clear → something else**

Without refresh screen and using `system("cls")` or like these.

Comment: Standard C++ has no screen manipulation facilities. You will have to use  OS-specific features, such as the Windows console API, or libraries such as curses.

Comment: then what can I do? I don't want the screen to blink

Comment: You have to do what I said - use OS features or a library.

Comment: ok, I'll try to do it

Comment: I found almost one solution, => clear by gotoxy(x,y), I can manually enter coordinates, but I want to enter by mouse position on the console too

Comment: What kind of application are you coding, and for what system and computer? I guess you want it to have a GUI, and then you should consider Qt. Please **edit your question** to improve it

Answer (score 3):

The [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) standard (check some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site, then read the standard i.e. [n3337](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n3337.pdf)) does not know about and does not mention screens. You can code C++ programs on computers without screens (e.g. web servers, embedded appliances, etc...), and notice that the [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) -e.g. [`std::cout`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) - might not be a screen (think of [redirections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) and pipelines), even on a laptop or desktop computer & OS (Windows, Linux, MacOSX, ...).

But many libraries might be useful to you. First, you can use OS specific libraries (e.g. [WinAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/apiindex/windows-api-list) on Windows). You can also target a [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) and use a library such as [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) (or similar), and you might even output directly [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)s (I don't recommend this). And you could want to develop a [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) application with toolkits like [Qt](http://qt.io/). You might even want to code a [Web application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application) (using HTTP server libraries like [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) or [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/), with more code in Javascript & HTML5).

I mentioned a few libraries, but you could find a lot more.

Be aware that [terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) (and their emulators) are complex devices and their OS support is chaotic (for historical reasons). For POSIX and Unix read [*the Tty Demystified*](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) and see also [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html). Have a glance at them even if you are using Windows, to feel how complex terminal emulators have to be.

In a comment, you mention "mouse". They are not known to the C++11 standard. My feeling is that an application handling the mouse should preferably provide a GUI (even if you could code a terminal application using the mouse thru other libraries or OS specific code), so I would recommend Qt (however, you might use some other [GUI toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit)).